# Close additional window (PApplet)

Tags: java, processing

How to close new frame without exiting whole application? 
What is easiest way to do it by clicking X button.
Thanks in advance.

```
ControlFrame cf;
void setup()
{
 cf = new ControlFrame(this,500,500, "cf name"); 
}

class ControlFrame extends PApplet
{
   int w,h;
   PApplet parent;

  public ControlFrame(PApplet _parent, int _w, int _h, String _name)
    {
    super();
    parent=_parent; w=_w; h=_h;
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{this.getClass().getName()},this); 
    }
  public void settings()
    { size(w,h); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with ControlP5.

**Step 1:** Get a reference to the native window. How you do this depends on the renderer you're using. If you're using the default renderer, it looks like this:

```
Frame frame = ( (SmoothCanvas) ((PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative()).getFrame();
```

**Step 2:** You can then call `dispose()` on that `Frame` to hide it without quititng the entire application.

```
frame.dispose();
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas;

ControlFrame cf;
void setup()
{
  cf = new ControlFrame(this, 500, 500, "cf name");
}

class ControlFrame extends PApplet
{
  int w, h;
  PApplet parent;

  public ControlFrame(PApplet _parent, int _w, int _h, String _name)
  {
    super();
    parent=_parent; 
    w=_w; 
    h=_h;
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{this.getClass().getName()}, this);

  }
  public void settings()
  { 
    size(w, h);
  }

  public void draw(){
    //needed for mousePressed
    println(millis());
  }

  public void mousePressed(){
    Frame frame = ( (SmoothCanvas) ((PSurfaceAWT)surface).getNative()).getFrame();
    frame.dispose();
  }

}
```

**Step 3:** Note that your second sketch will continue running, so you might also want to call `noLoop()` to prevent unnecessary computation.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I edited flags because question have nothing to do with ContolP5. I use this windows as controlP5 UI for my program, so it won't work with noLoop().
I have "No library found for processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT" error which is strange because your solution work very well.

Comment: @MaciejWójcik That's not an error. It's just a warning. You can ignore it.